# How to create subdomains on a name-based virtualhost?

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host, subdomain

I have name-based hosting, lets call it `my.address.com`. My friend has the 'plain' address `address.com` and gave me a virtual machine that I can access via SSH.

He also made some magic with ports and now, after installing Apache, I could access `/var/www` through `my.address.com`.

So, the question is, how can I make a subdomain like `test.my.address.com`?

There should be some magic with [Apache's Listen Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen), but I cant figure it out. Also, I know how to create local-available sites with Apache, but it is not the same.

Comment: You won't need `Listen`, look at Apaches virtual hosts: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: the main question is remained - what to write in ServerName directive?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To be able to create subdomains, you'll have to make sure of several things:

### DNS

So other's can reach `test.my.address.com`, they first have to be able to resolve that name to the IP address of your virtual machine. How can that be done?

What your friend most likely already did, was to create an [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_DNS_record_types#A) in the `address.com` zone, which points `my` to the IP address of your VM.

So far, so good. But what about `test.my`? It might not have an entry yet.

Your friend could simply add `*.my` to the zone as well (and point it to the same IP address). Then all request to `something.my.address.com` would be send to your VM. Great!

### Apache Virtual Hosts

Once your VM can be reached, Apache has to know how to handle the request. This is where we use the [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) feature of the Apache HTTP server.

I usually run on Debian, so I'll explain this with an example configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Let's have a file there called `test.my.address.com` and fill it with information.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.my.address.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@my.address.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.my.address.com/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/test.my.address.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.my.address.com.error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.my.address.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The **key setting** inside this file is the [`ServerName` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername). This tells Apache under which name this *server* should be available. Additional names can be given with the [ServerAlias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).

In case you're using Debian as well, don't forget to `sudo a2ensite test.my.address.com` after you created the file and `sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!:) I made my part, and wrote email to friend about his part. Thank again:)

Comment: @scythargon: My pleasure. We're here to help :)

Comment: While my friend did not answer my, can you, please? What I was thought  about how it works: http-request for `test.my.address.com` goes to `my.address.com` and then **my Apache server on VM** handles it. But you said that DNS-server at address.com should know about `test.my` before all of this and independently of knowledge about `my`, why?

Comment: @scythargon: For any HTTP request to reach your server, any client first has to figure out to what server the request has to be sent. So the hostname has to be valid. Otherwise they'll just be told "that name does not exist".